# Max rows a django model can retrieve via model.objects.all()

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

In of my models, there exist 2 million rows and I query this based on a date range. When setting a limit to around 100-1000 rows, the query runs but when the number of rows is e.g. 100k then the query doesn't seem to run.

My question is, is there a limit to how many queries a django model can make and if so what is it?

```
queryset = Overall.objects.all()[:1000] ## works
queryset = Overall.objects.all() ## doesn't work

serializer = OverallSerializer(queryset, many=True)
data = serializer.data
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no practical limit, but you will run into an issue where the result being fetched from the database exceeds the memory available to the process. Server-side cursors and iteration is a way around this. Currently server-side cursors aren't natively supported with the ORM, see [Django ticket #16614](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16614).